# ApiProperty for unknown key/value pair in NestJS Swagger

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am using Nest (v10). I have a DTO that defines a response:

```
export class ProfileDto {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Michael' })
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Johnson' })
  surname: string;

  // more properties
}

export class TodoDto {
  [userId: string]: ProfileDto;
}
```

Right now, I get an empty object in Swagger `{}` for the `TodoDto` schema. How can I define the type of `TodoDto`? Even if it's an empty string as key `{ "": { name: "Michael"} }` it would be ok. If I could actually define an example key that would be even better.